# Angular + .net Core 3 + Azure App Service- Allow HTTP on specific route only?

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, web, azure-web-app-service

I've got a project that has an interesting scenario.

I've got to deploy a SOAP service (using soap core) into the environment, and it has to allow http-- the client app consuming it is old, already compiled, and wont' work with https (i tried).

however, I want literally EVERYTHING else http only, not https.

so I'm looking for a specific route:  myservice/theservice.asmx  to allow HTTPS, and everything else not so much.

I'm deployed into a windows appservice.

I could split this soap service out into another app service if I had to, but I would prefer to not.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my own question:

```
  app.UseWhen(httpContext => !httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/pga4"),
                subApp => subApp.UseHttpsRedirection());
```

this allows you to conditionally apply middleware based on path.
(subApp acts same as `app.Usexxx()`, but only in this conditional context).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to filter and fix each http/s request that gets sent out?

A very rough example:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.match(/myservice\/theservice\.asmx$/)) {
      request = request.clone({
        url: request.url.replace('https:', 'http:')
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```